# Vuetify Error - "Cannot read property of 'extend' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I'm currently getting the following console error after installing Vuetify. I'm using webpack v3.6

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'extend' of undefined
    at Module../src/mixins/themeable/index.ts (index.ts:21)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/components/VApp/VApp.ts (vuetify.js:391)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/components/VApp/index.ts (index.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/components/index.ts (index.ts:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../src/index.ts (vuetify.js:32032)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
./src/mixins/themeable/index.ts @ index.ts:21
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/components/VApp/VApp.ts @ vuetify.js:391
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/components/VApp/index.ts @ index.ts:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/components/index.ts @ index.ts:1
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
./src/index.ts @ vuetify.js:32032
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
webpackUniversalModuleDefinition @ universalModuleDefinition:9
(anonymous) @ universalModuleDefinition:10
```

Has anyone experienced anything similar? I have included vuetify as a plugin like this:

```
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

Then imported it into my main.js file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

import router from './router'
import { store } from './store/store'

import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'

import vuetify from '@/plugins/vuetify'

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

Vue.config.productionTip = true

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Why are you using two ui libraries? one is sufficient

Comment: There are some components in vuetify that I would like to use but I'm familiar with bootstrap for the general design

Comment: but this will generates some conflicts

Comment: Ended up removing vuetify and recreating the components I needed

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error after adding vuetify ^2.5.1 to an existing project, only to realize that I was using vue ^3.0.0.
Unfortunately vuetify does not support Vue 3.0 (yet... as of May 2021).

Comment: It's on alpha - https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#vue-cli